# How to call awk script in java file?

Tags: java, awk

I have an awk script which filters the file contents and i want that awk script to be called from java file.How to do ?

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  Exec'ing in java is terribly inefficient.  An Exec requires copying the entire running process in memory in order to fork it and then overwriting that copy with the image of the new executable.  Given the bloated size of the typical java process given the overhead of the JVM, this is problematic.  You would be much better off to convert the awk script to native java, or build/find a native java awk interpreter.

Comment: can to tell me how to convert awk to native java ?

Comment: A specific script perhaps, but any arbitrary script would require some work.  Checkout http://awk.info/?jawk

Answer (score 0):

Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/your/awk_script")`

Take a look to [Class Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: where to give file name which awk script takes for process ?

Comment: replace "/path/to/your/awk_script" with the path of the awk script

Comment: By path I mean the path+filename

Comment: //code to load file into awk script and read
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gawk -f a1.awk svce2.tr");
showing error

Comment: @user3190104, please, do some _mental effort_.

Comment: I am not able to get output 
     String [] cmd ={

        "#!/usr/bin/awk -f", "awk -f a1.awk svce2.tr"};
           Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
           java.io.InputStream is=p.getInputStream();
           java.util.Scanner s=new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
           String val="";
             p.waitFor();
             if(s.hasNext()){val=s.next();}
             System.out.println(val);

Answer (score 0):

I had to support some script commands via a remote console interface, it was relatively straightforward, if tedious.  The process will be the same with most apps running a script file such as an awk script.

I was having trouble, until I started using an approach based on this posting.

- [When Runtime Exec -- Won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html#resources)

The main issue will not be what to do to fire the script, it is how to manage the output stream and stderr.  That design decision will depend on your use case.  You my just toss output away or store the "*interesting*" parts, whatever.

Again, depending on your circumstances it might be better to open a pipe between your awk script and your java program.  You will get exactly the same results (more or less) with somewhat less hassle and some additional flexibility.

Finally I don't really understand the comment about *using exec* above.  An exec function is an operating system call, just like opening a file.  Overheads will depend on the o/s.  Again though if it is a long-lived partnership consider the use of a pipe to tie them together.  Good luck.